# ELSE value not executed in CASE expression PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm using CASE expression to display "NamaAyah" or "NamaIbu" or "NamaWali", and if all of them is empty, the default value will display "ORTU-'NomorPokok' ".
But the default value not displayed, it just displays symbol "-" in my table. I think the value in ELSE statement not executed.

Postgre Version : PostgreSQL 9.4.15

This is my code

```
SELECT
"MahasiswaID" AS "PERSONID","NomorPokok" AS "KODE",
UPPER(CASE 
                    WHEN "NamaAyah" <> '' THEN "NamaAyah" 
                    WHEN "NamaIbu" <> '' THEN "NamaIbu"
                    WHEN "NamaWali" <> '' THEN "NamaWali"
                    ELSE 'ORTU'||'-'||"NomorPokok"
                    END) AS "NAMALENGKAP"
FROM "MasterMahasiswa" ORDER BY "KODE"
```

and this is the result
[image]

[image]

Comment: please share the `CREATE TABLE` statements, `INSERT INTO` statements for some data sample that reproduces the problem and the version of Postgres you're using. Please edit the question to do so. Don't use comments.

Comment: I'm not too sure to do that ... I'm not the one who made this table. this table has 121 fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you have can simpler be:

```
ELSE 'ORTU-'||"NomorPokok"
```

Apart from that, the only reasonable explanation for what you display is that there are literal `-` in one or more of your columns `"NamaAyah"`, `"NamaIbu"` and `"NamaWali"`. Did you check that?

Comment: I have checked it before, and it turns out there is indeed a '-' symbol in the "NamaIbu" column for empty data